# How to code the profilling of multiple metrics from Nvidia CUDA gpu cards?

Tags: cuda

I'm trying to code a kernel profilling on my source code, and it needs to profile multiple metrics on CUDA kernels. I've tried PAPI with the CUDA component, but it's doens't worked out. I also noticed the NVidia CUPTI API, but the sample code callback_metrics only profiles one metric per kernel and I'm a bit confused on how to change the sample source code to perform under multiple metrics.
PS: the nvprof tool doens't help, because the profilling must happens on my source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CUPTI API uses multiple techniques to collect data from the GPU. Each techniques has limitations in what data can be collected in a single kernel. In order to collect more complicated metrics or multiple metrics CUPTI the kernel launch has to be replayed multiple times. CUPTI has a feature called kernel replay that can transparently replay a kernel multiple times within your application. From a CUDA API perspective it looks like the kernel took many times longer to execute. This feature can be enabled by calling

```
CUptiResult CUPTIAPI cuptiEnableKernelReplayMode(CUcontext context);
```

This will change the collection mode to CUPTI_EVENT_COLLECTION_MODE_KERNEL.

See *cupti_events.h* and the *CUPTI User Guide* section [CUPTI Event API](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cupti/r_main.html#r_event_api) for additional information regarding collection of events.